# Ext JS 5.0.1 - grid/store with memory proxy ignores pageSize

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm trying to have a Grid that only shows one Page of the data in it's Store.  I'm loading the data via Ajax here - please don't suggest to change it to an ajax-loading proxy.

It's showing all 10 records, rather than a Page of 3 at a time.
Suggestions?

```
 Ext.onReady(function() {

 var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
 storeId: 'levelStore',
 fields: ['title'],
 pageSize: 3,
 proxy: {
   type: 'memory',
   enablePaging: true,
   reader: {
     type: 'json',
     rootProperty: 'articles'
   }
 }
});

Ext.Ajax.request({
 url: 'https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=abc-news-au&apiKey=9340458d9514498c84b153ac9050aa04',
 success: function(xhr) {
   var r = Ext.JSON.decode(xhr.responseText);
   Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('levelStore').loadData(r.articles);
 }
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
 store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('levelStore'),
 pageSize: 3,
 dockedItems: [{
   xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
   pageSize: 3,
   store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('levelStore'), 
   displayInfo: true
 }],
 columns: [{
   text: 'title',
   dataIndex: 'title',
   flex: 1
 }],
 height: 200,
 width: 400,
 renderTo: 'main'
 });
});
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/08qzn8nr/)

Comment: You're never going through the proxy, the data is being added to the store directly. You need to specify the data on the proxy.

Comment: thanks.  I changed the store load to `Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('levelStore').proxy.setData(r.articles);` and it works, but it doesn't display the records until I hit `reload` on the Paging Toolbar.  Is there a call I can need to make to have the same effect?

Comment: It acts the same as any other store that needs to fetch data from a proxy, you need to load the store.